# Monitoring CPU usage of IIS7 worker processes

Tags: iis-7, monitoring, worker-processes

What is the best way to monitor IIS7 worker processes and store informations about websites which are using CPU/memory too much?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently started looking at accessing WMI with ASP.NET.  Assuming your ASP Service Account has enough permissions you can query and even monitor the various performance metrics using the standard WMI method calls.  You might want to start out by looking at O'Reilly Media's article [A Quick Introduction to WMI from .NET](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/07/wmi.html) and see if that satisfies your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [commercial options](http://www.servernanny.com/) that will monitor a process's CPU and memory utilization.

But there is also a [solution on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/processescpuusage.aspx) that will let you tap into the values to monitor them from a winform application.

Answer (score 0):

We recently started to use commercial product [new relic](http://newrelic.com/product/real-user-monitoring) and very impressed with it. It has good dashboard and highlights the CPU,memory, slow SQL etc issues with monitoring servers.